# How to open a binary pipe with Powershell

Tags: powershell

As far as I have read Powershell can not redirect input streams. Instead one has to use `Get-Content` to pipe the result to the target program. But this seems to create text streams.

I tried to pipe binary data to plink:

```
Get-Content client.zip | & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe' unix nop
```

The target system 'unix' is a Debian with a fixed command in the `authorized_keys` file.

This are the first bytes of the file I tried to transfer:

```
00000000  50 4b 03 04 0a 00 00 00  00 00 6f 4a 59 50 c8 cb  |PK........oJYP..|
```

And this is what arrived on the target system:

```
00000000  50 4b 03 04 0d 0a 00 00  00 00 00 6f 4a 59 50 3f  |PK.........oJYP?|
```

'0a' gets replaced by '0d 0a'. I am not sure, but I suppose `Get-Content` does this.

How to pipe binary data with Powershell?

I installed already Powershell 6. I tried already the options -AsByteStream -ReadCount -Raw and I get may different funny results. But nothing gives my just an exact copy of the zip file. Where is the option "--stop-doing-anything-with-my-file"?

Comment: Did you try `Get-Content -Path client.zip -Encoding Byte` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it myself. This seems to do what I want:

```
Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe' -ArgumentList "unix nop" -RedirectStandardInput .\client.zip -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
# read binary
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('client.zip')

# pipe all Bytes to external prg
$bytes | & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe' unix nop
```

Comment: This generates a text file and each line contains the decimal value of each byte of the zip file. This is one of the funny results, I mentioned in my question.