# How do I pipe a byte stream to/from an external command?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

Using [`Get-Content -AsByteStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content#code-try-8), one can read file as a byte stream.

Using [`Set-Content -AsByteStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content#parameters), one can create a file from a byte stream.

However, I haven't found a way to pass these byte streams to other non-PowerShell commands. Pipes between external commands always decode the data as a string, which mangle binaries.

[`cmd /c --%`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44193983/188256) or [`Start-Process -RedirectStandardInput`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60392751/188256) do solve part of the problem, but it can get a bit tedious if any of involved commands is another cmdlet. Is there a PowerShell-native way to handle executable input/output as a stream of byte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [<s>open</s> closed issue on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1908) for that. The thread is full of a variety of workarounds. (found via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/188256))

**Edit:** There is a [PowerShell Module to wrap native commands](https://github.com/GeeLaw/PowerShellThingies/tree/master/modules/Use-RawPipeline) by [@GeeLaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4598348/gee-law) though I haven't tried.

**Edit^2(2023-06-29)**: [@SeeminglyScience](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1930135/patrick-meinecke) implemented awesome [`PSNativeCommandPreserveBytePipe` experimental feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/experimental-features?view=powershell-7.3#psnativecommandpreservebytepipe) and it's incorporated as part of [v7.4.0-preview.4](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.4.0-preview.4#:%7E:text=(%2317857)). It can be enabled with `Enable-ExperimentalFeature PSNativeCommandPreserveBytePipe`.

**Edit^3(2023-11-16)**: [PowerShell 7.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-74?view=powershell-7.4#:%7E:text=PSNativeCommandPreserveBytePipe) has been released. The feature has become built-in, so `cmd /c type a.zip > b.zip` should work by default now.